# Posting in behalf of Wordpress "Contributor" user

Tags: wordpress

I have a news website belongs to old school, and I am receiving articles/opinions through email, and I manage adding theme my self.

I am planning now to switch to Wordpress and until I can enable all writers to post their articles by giving them "Contributor" role, is there any Wordpress plugin that enable Admin/Author to post an article in behalf of any "Contributor" user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editors don't need a plugin for this.  On the admin page in which you edit posts (or pages) near the bottom there's a dropdown list from which your editor can select the post's author. The selected author shows up as the post's author on the front end.

Your contributors will be able to write and edit their own posts. But, only an editor or administrator can publish them: make them visible on the front end.

That's handy: it lets you have contributors you don't trust completely. Editors vet their work before it shows up on the site.

But, if your editors aren't diligent, your contributors will never see their work published. On a volunteer site (such as your application) they'll become discouraged and stop writing stuff.

You may want to err on the side of letting people publish stuff, then removing it if you don't like it, or if it's spam, or whatever. To do that you make people "editors" rather than contributors.

Comment: Also in the list of posts, quick edit, change author.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , learn [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) about the editor role , you can create as many as editors from wp-admin panel and editors can create and modify the posts via their provided login or their created login.

Editor capabilities : https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor

You can also manage their capabilities by using : [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any such plugins but if the number of articles posted by contributors are less than you can simply write that article and publish it. Once publish you can than change the author to any contributor from the list on the posts page.